# Xcode 4 - Create shortcut for tabs

Tags: xcode, applescript

Is there a way to assign shortcut to applescript that can control tabs on Xcode 4 ? Something like this works for Safari, but not Xcode 4 :

```
try
    tell front window of application "Xcode" to set current tab to tab 1
on error
    tell front window of application "Xcode" to set current tab to last tab
end try
```

(I have an error : `A property can’t go after this identifier.`)

I know I can switch tabs with `cmd-}`, I want to be able to go to a tab by its number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Xcode 4 is so young, the Applescript dictionary is basically empty.  You may have to wait for Xcode 4.1 or 4.2 before you can do any kind of complicated scripting.

I would file a radar bug if this is really important to you.  It's like voting.  If you are lucky enough to have a WWDC ticket, make sure to mention it to all the apple engineers you meet there.

Xcode 4 was an ambitious redesign.  In an effort to ship, quite a few features got cut (applescript, user scripts being the more glaring).  I would expect them to make a comeback over time, but you need to make your needs known.